# ssh connection refused after editing fstab in Google cloud vm

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, gcloud, fstab

I'm getting `ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Connection refused` after updating `fstab` for mounting Google bucket. fstab entry that I have added is as follows,

```
bucket mount_point fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1004,group_id=1005,default_permissions 0 0
```

ssh connection is came up after updating fstab and restarting the vm. Is there a relationship between fstab entry and ssh connection issue? and how I'm supposed to change fstab entry while I can't connect vm through ssh?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should ask questions like this on [sf] or [su].

Comment: Could you provide the verbose output from the ssh command? (e.g. `ssh -vvv host_name`)

Comment: @Kenster, Thank you for your advice. I have posted my question on the https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Changes to **/etc/fstab** should not cause a problem with SSH

I would start by checking the firewall rules of your project

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
```

Add default-allow-ssh rule if it is missing

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-ssh --allow tcp:22
```

Did you install a firewall in the OS?
If you could share the output of nmap against the external IP of your instance it will be great.

Comment: Firewall is already installed and enabled by default. Also same firewall rule for ssh connections has applied to all vms. After connecting through the serial port connection I have removed the fstab entry and restarted the vm. Then I was able to connect to my vm using ssh.